# Export file list from ZIP archive without unzipping

Tags: xml, perl, cmd, zip, archive

I have hundreds of ZIP archives and each of them contains 2000 to 4000 xml files in it. Now I need some way to get a text file that will contain list of these xml files or at least file counts from each archive.

Is there any application to do this, or can I do this through cmd or perl?

I am not an expert programmer

Comment: Are you at least `enthusiast programmer`? http://snag.gy/iW5Ow.jpg

Comment: You can use the command line UNZIP or 7-Zip etc with a command line switch to list the contents of the zip files.  More information about the task, and which archiver you can use, is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip;

my $archive_name = "archive.zip";

my $archive_extract = Archive::Zip -> new ( $archive_name );
foreach my $member ( $archive_extract -> members() )
{
  print $member -> fileName(),"\n";
}
```

You will, of course, need to supply your own directory search. I would recommend looking at `File::Find` for that

Comment: The program runs like a charm, I exported the file list to a text file with `>file.txt` in cmd, and I need another help, can I get the file counts inside each archive in a text file and also a loop to go around some n number of archives placed in a folder?

Answer (score 3):

[`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aZip) can be used to read a zip file and it's members.

The module includes an [`examples directory`](https://metacpan.org/source/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.37/examples) that has a lot of useful scripts showing how to use the module.